# Windows 10 Mail - won't show full email "Download messages and pictures

Tags: email, windows-10

I have just purchased a Windows 8.1 desktop computer and set it up using my personal Xtra (pop3 server in New Zealand) email address as my Microsoft account.

I then upgraded to Windows 10. I've been able to set up my Gmail, my work email on an Exchange server and another Xtra account I have and they all work fine in Mail.  The email address I used to set it up is the only one not working. It automatically loaded into Mail and all of the emails loaded but I can't view them - I get the message "Download message and pictures (45.2KB) or similar KB depending on the size of the email. I'm also not always able to look at any of the settings for this email account - they are sometimes greyed out, but not always.

I have since uninstalled Windows 10, changed my login to an outlook.com email address and reinstalled Windows 10.  The outlook.com email set itself up in Mail and shows all emails fine.  I then added all of my email accounts again.  They all added fine to Mail and the 2 Xtra accounts added also. However my personal Xtra account still loads all emails but I can't view them and I still get the message "Download messages and pictures"(....KB). I've gone online and was able to look at the emails through Yahoo and know I have the password correct.  I also know the pop server works with Mail and Windows 10 as the other Xtra email address works fine.  Can you please help?

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be a bug - I have tried just about all of the suggestions out there and absolutely nothing worked. That is until I came across a solution posted on a forum, which I have been unable to find again to post a 'thank you'.

This worked for me, so I have posted it here in the hope it will help others too.

Click the 'Forward' link. In the new mail that is created the original email will appear. Close the forwarded email and the mail body will then show in the originally received mail.

Not a very elegant solution, but saves hours of re-installing, or standing in the corner of the room with one foot in a bucket of iced water whilst pointing north and all the other suggestions out there.

Comment: This solution just works. Thank you @Giles for this simple yet working tip. On MS Technet website they say it's a bug and the solution is to reset the mail app!

Comment: This used to work until recently, but unfortunately as of today (June 2021), this doesn't seem to do the trick anymore. Once again, Microsoft fails at something spectacularly simple.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. The Download Messages and Pictures link would not work. Another support page suggested the following: Close the Mail app, go to Windows Settings (gear icon), click on Apps, choose the Mail and Calendar app from the list, click the Advanced Options link, and then click the Reset button. When I reopened the app, this did the trick for me.

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings General and turn off Smart Screen filter.

All emails then worked fine for me.

Comment: I would strongly advise NOT to turn off smart screen filter. It is against malware.